# WebSocket connection to failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I am using Ratchet to create websockets for a chat and I get an error that says:

`main.js`:2 WebSocket connection to `ws://localhost:8080/`

`failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

The code from which I get the error is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    var chatForm = $(".chatForm"),
        messageInputField = chatForm.find("#message"),
        messagesList = $(".messages-list"),
        usernameForm = $(".username-setter"),
        usernameInput = usernameForm.find(".username-input");
```

I also changed the IP in the `/etc/host` to `0.0.0.0` just to be sure.
Anything you can suggest to change and fix this error?